# How to zoom all nokia here map markers stored in array value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, here-api

I want to ask how can I zoom to all marker that stored in an array using JavaScript..
Thank you guys in advance.

Here is my code..

```
    $.each(data, function(i,val){

        outletMarkers[val.id] = new Array();

        var lat = parseFloat(val.latitude);
        var lng = parseFloat(val.longitude);

        outletMarkers[val.id] = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(

            [lat,lng],
            {
                text: val.text,
                $click  : 'showBubble("'+val.text+'",'+lat+','+lng+',false,"'+val.id+'");'                }


        );

        map.objects.add(outletMarkers[val.id]); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to do this, to create a container, add all makers to container and zoom to map.
for example:

var myContainer = new nokia.maps.map.Container();

$.each(data, function(i,val){

```
    outletMarkers[val.id] = new Array();

    var lat = parseFloat(val.latitude);
    var lng = parseFloat(val.longitude);

    outletMarkers[val.id] = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(

        [lat,lng],
        {
            text: val.text,
            $click  : 'showBubble("'+val.text+'",'+lat+','+lng+',false,"'+val.id+'");'
        }
    );
```

myContainer.objects.add(outletMarkers[val.id]);// add all makers to the container 
    });

Add the container to the map
map.objects.add(myContainer);

Zoom to all makers 
map.zoomTo(myContainer.getBoundingBox());